# HDFS balancing , how to balance hdfs data

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

We have **HDP version - 2.6.4**. On the datanode machine we can see that hdfs data isn’t balanced. On some disks we have different size as

```
sdb 11G 
and 
sdd 17G


/dev/sdd 20G 3.0G 17G 15% /grid/sdd 
/dev/sdb 20G 11G 9.3G 53% /grid/sdb <-- Why disks are not balanced?
```

After searching in google I found the following CLI 
( from https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/19694/help-with-exception-from-hdfs-balancer.html )

```
hdfs balancer -Ddfs.balancer.movedWinWidth=5400000 -Ddfs.balancer.moverThreads=1000 -Ddfs.balancer.dispatcherThreads=200 -Ddfs.datanode.balance.bandwidthPerSec=100000000 -Ddfs.balancer.max-size-to-move=10737418240 -threshold 20 1>/tmp/balancer-out.log 2>/tmp/balancer-debug.log
```

and after I run it we get the same hdfs size

```
/dev/sdd 20G 3.0G 17G 15% /grid/sdd
/dev/sdb 20G 11G 9.3G 53% /grid/sdb


more /tmp/balancer-out.log Time Stamp Iteration# Bytes Already Moved Bytes Left To Move Bytes Being Moved The cluster is balanced. Exiting... Mar 7, 2019 5:02:34 PM 0 0 B 0 B 0 B Mar 7, 2019 5:02:34 PM Balancing took 1.453 seconds
```

So actually we do not see any difference in disk balancing in hdfs.

How to balance the hdfs data so all disk will be with the same used size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not an expert on this, I've only just started looking at it. I suspect you should be using [hdfs diskbalancer](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HDFSDiskbalancer.html), not balancer.